# How do you permanently fix grub rescue: unkown filesystem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grubrescue

I have a dual-boot of Ubuntu and Windows 10(dev/sda1)
And it shows me this:

```
grub rescue: Unknown Filesystem
grub rescue>
```

And this is what I have to type to fix it:

```
grub rescue> set boot=(hd0,msdos6)
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
grub rescue> insmod normal
grub rescue> normal
```

But I have to type this every time I restart my PC. Is there a way to make this fix permanent and update grub? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After those commands you type on grub rescue, you should update grub once you boot into Ubuntu, by running:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

and then:

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

After this is done, reboot your system and check if the problem remains.